# How to reject numeric values in Lucene.net?

Tags: lucene.net

I want to know whether is it possible to reject numeric phrases or numeric values while indexing or searching in Lucene.net.

For example (this is one line),

```
Hi all my no is 4756396
```

Now, when I index or search it should reject the numeric value 4756396 to be indexed or searched. I tried making a custom stop word list with 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, etc, but I guess it will only ignore if a single number will appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the `StandardAnalyzer` and customize the grammar (simple JFlex stuff) to reject number tokens. If you do that, you'll need to port back the analyzer to Java since JFlex will generate java code, tho you could give it a try with C# Flex.

You could also write a `TokenFilter` that scans tokens one by one and rejects them if they are numbers. If you wanna filter only whole numbers and still retain numbers that are for example separate by hyphens, the filter could simply attempt a `double.TryParse()` and if it fails you accept the Token. A more robust and customizable solution would still use a lexical parser.

### Edit:

Heres a quick sample of what I mean, with a little main method that shows how to use it. In this I used a `TryParse()` to filter out tokens, if it were for a more complex production system I'd use a lexical parser system. (take a look at [C# Flex](http://sourceforge.net/projects/csflex/) for that)

```cs
public class NumericFilter : TokenFilter
{
    private ITermAttribute termAtt ;

    public NumericFilter(TokenStream tokStream)
        : base(tokStream)
    {
        termAtt = AddAttribute<ITermAttribute>();
    }

    public override bool IncrementToken()
    {
        while (base.input.IncrementToken())
        {
            string term = termAtt.Term;
            double res ;
            if(double.TryParse(term, out res))
            {
                // skip this token
                continue;
            }
            // accept this token
            return true;
        }
        // no more token in the stream
        return false;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    RAMDirectory dir = new RAMDirectory();
    IndexWriter iw = new IndexWriter(dir, new KeywordAnalyzer(), IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);

    Document d = new Document();
    Field f = new Field("text", "", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED);
    d.Add(f);

    // use our Filter here
    f.SetTokenStream(new NumericFilter(new LowerCaseFilter(new WhitespaceTokenizer(new StringReader("I have 300 dollars")))));
    iw.AddDocument(d);

    iw.Commit();
    IndexReader reader = iw.GetReader();
    // print all terms in the text field
    TermEnum terms = reader.Terms(new Term("text", ""));
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine(terms.Term.Text);
    }
    while (terms.Next());

    reader.Dispose();
    iw.Dispose();
    Console.ReadLine();
    Environment.Exit(42);
}
```

Comment: Thanks JFBeaulac for the quick answer.i would like to implement TokenFilter.Can you provide me a example for it?

Comment: Thanks loads JF..u really saved my day..That's what i was looking for.